# Python Selenium iFrame - how to move mouse and click?

Tags: python, selenium

Python Selenium iFrame - how to move mouse and click? 
There are the events with js. I dont really know, how to make it with python selenium.

```
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
```

I tried this method, but it didnt work.

Comment: Try `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over).click().build().perform()`

Answer (score 0):

For me pyautogui worked.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

You can combine it with selenium by giving suitable time.sleep()